# MPI io reading file by processes equally by line (not by chunk size)

Tags: c, mpi

I am new to MPI and I have this problem. I want to read the contents of a file which has more than 20000 lines and then divide those lines equally to all processes for further processing. The contents of each line in the file are something like this (two column of numbers),

```
45.87   13.22
45.71   13.27
45.78   13.21
45.67   13.1
45.7    13.24
45.81   13.28
45.85   13.32
```

I need to divide the lines equally to any number of process at run time (number of process can be for eg; 2,3,4,5,....,128)

I know how to divide the file into a chunk but I need to preserve the values in each line so I need to read line by line.

Here is the MPI code and serial code that I have been using to get this done but I encountered segmentation fault.

```
/* Open the file */
MPI_File_open (MPI_COMM_WORLD, "small.txt", MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &myfile);
/* Get the size of the file */
MPI_File_get_size(myfile, &filesize);
/* Calculate how many elements that is */
filesize = filesize/sizeof(char);

/* Calculate how many elements each processor gets */
bufsize = filesize/np;
/* Allocate the buffer to read to, one extra for terminating null char */
buf = (char *) malloc((bufsize+1)*sizeof(char));


/* Set the file view */
MPI_File_set_view(myfile, myid*bufsize*sizeof(char), MPI_CHAR, MPI_CHAR,"native",MPI_INFO_NULL);


Nooflines_Real = count_lines(myfile);
printf("%s contains %d lines\n", argv[1], Nooflines_Real);


int count_lines (FILE *infile) {
  char readline[80];
  int lines=0;
  while( fgets(readline,80,infile) != NULL ) lines++;
  rewind(infile);
  return(lines);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where in the code this segmentation fault occurred?

Comment: the segmentation fault is a result after adding the codes
Nooflines_Real = count_lines(myfile);

Comment: I've fleshed out the answer below with working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument `myfile` is a variable of type `MPI_File`, not of `FILE *`, so you can't use it for things like `fgets()`, `rewind()`, etc.   That's probably the source of your segfault.

My suggestion would be to take the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942718/463827) and read overlapping chunks per file (to account for the fact that you don't know how long a line is), each task read in their chunk and process `their` lines.  If you're really concerned with each file having exactly the same number of lines (to the extent possible), you can have them exchange data with each other to have precisely the same number of lines.

**Update**:  If you really want to do this (note that if your input is all numbers, this would be so much easier in a binary format), some code that reads in the text files, partitions as in the other number, then processes each line (say by summing the columns) follows as a straightforward extension from the answer I linked to above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void readlines(MPI_File *in, const int rank, const int size, const int overlap,
               char ***lines, int *nlines) {
    MPI_Offset filesize;
    MPI_Offset localsize;
    MPI_Offset start;
    MPI_Offset end;
    char *chunk;

    /* figure out who reads what */

    MPI_File_get_size(*in, &filesize);
    localsize = filesize/size;
    start = rank * localsize;
    end   = start + localsize - 1;

    /* add overlap to the end of everyone's chunk... */
    end += overlap;

    /* except the last processor, of course */
    if (rank == size-1) end = filesize;

    localsize =  end - start + 1;

    /* allocate memory */
    chunk = malloc( (localsize + 1)*sizeof(char));

    /* everyone reads in their part */
    MPI_File_read_at_all(*in, start, chunk, localsize, MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    chunk[localsize] = '\0';

    /*
     * everyone calculate what their start and end *really* are by going 
     * from the first newline after start to the first newline after the
     * overlap region starts (eg, after end - overlap + 1)
     */

    int locstart=0, locend=localsize;
    if (rank != 0) {
        while(chunk[locstart] != '\n') locstart++;
        locstart++;
    }
    if (rank != size-1) {
        locend-=overlap;
        while(chunk[locend] != '\n') locend++;
    }
    localsize = locend-locstart+1;

    /* Now let's copy our actual data over into a new array, with no overlaps */
    char *data = (char *)malloc((localsize+1)*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(data, &(chunk[locstart]), localsize);
    data[localsize] = '\0';
    free(chunk);

    /* Now we'll count the number of lines */
    *nlines = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<localsize; i++)
        if (data[i] == '\n') (*nlines)++;

    /* Now the array lines will point into the data array at the start of each line */
    /* assuming nlines > 1 */
    *lines = (char **)malloc((*nlines)*sizeof(char *));
    (*lines)[0] = strtok(data,"\n");
    for (int i=1; i<(*nlines); i++)
        (*lines)[i] = strtok(NULL, "\n");

    return;
}

void processlines(char **lines, const int nlines, const int rank) {
    for (int i=0; i<nlines; i++) {
        float a, b;
        sscanf(lines[i],"%f %f", &a, &b);
        printf("%d: <%s>: %f + %f = %f\n", rank, lines[i], a, b, a+b);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_File in;
    int rank, size;
    int ierr;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (argc != 2) {
        if (rank == 0) fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infilename\n", argv[0]);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }

    ierr = MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[1], MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &in);
    if (ierr) {
        if (rank == 0) fprintf(stderr, "%s: Couldn't open file %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(2);
    }

    const int overlap=100;
    char **lines;
    int nlines;
    readlines(&in, rank, size, overlap, &lines, &nlines);

    printf("Rank %d has %d lines\n", rank, nlines);

    processlines(lines, nlines, rank);

    free(lines[0]);
    free(lines);

    MPI_File_close(&in);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

And running this on your supplied data set:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./textio foo2.in 
Rank 0 has 4 lines
0: <45.87   13.22>: 45.869999 + 13.220000 = 59.090000
0: <45.71   13.27>: 45.709999 + 13.270000 = 58.980000
0: <45.78   13.21>: 45.779999 + 13.210000 = 58.989998
0: <45.67   13.1>: 45.669998 + 13.100000 = 58.769997
Rank 1 has 3 lines
1: <45.7    13.24>: 45.700001 + 13.240000 = 58.940002
1: <45.81   13.28>: 45.810001 + 13.280000 = 59.090000
1: <45.85   13.32>: 45.849998 + 13.320000 = 59.169998
```

Comment: By the way what could be the solution to the segfault caused by the different type of file pointers.

Comment: The solution is you stop calling posix file calls that expect `FILE *` on things that are of type `MPI_File`.  If you have an MPI_File, you call MPI-IO routines on it - MPI_File_read, MPI_File_seek, etc.

Comment: thanks, can you point me to some place where i can find reference for MPI-IO routnies

Comment: @user1733911, the MPI standard document is a great source of both reference information and (sometimes) useful examples. You can find it both in PDF and in HTML [here](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/docs.html). Stick to MPI-2.2 for now as MPI-3.0 is very very new and most MPI implementations still only conform to v2.2.

Comment: @JonathanDursi how can we combine the outputs of Rank 0 and Rank 1?

Comment: @TameenMalik - I'm not sure I understand the question: combine how?

Comment: @JonathanDursi I mean how to combine the results of rank 0 and rank 1. In your case, i want to send all results of processors to one dedicated processor say 0 to show work done by each processor.