# analyze text file in parallel with mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi4py

I have an input tab separated text file:

```
0   .4
1   .9
2   .2
3   .12
4   .55
5   .98
```

I analyze it in plain Python as:

```
lines = open("songs.tsv").readlines()

def extract_hotness(line):
        return float(line.split()[1])

songs_hotness =map(extract_hotness, lines)
max_hotness = max(songs_hotness)
```

How do I perform the same operation in parallel using `mpi4py`?
I started implementing this with `scatter`, but that won't work straight away because `scatter` needs list elements to be the same length as the number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Processing a text file in parallel is difficult.  Where do you split the file?  Are you even reading from a parallel file system?  You might consider MPI-IO if you have a large enough input file.  If you go that route, these answers, provided in a C context, describe the challenges that still hold in mpi4py: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31726730/1024740  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942718/1024740

Another approach is not to scatter the data but to read it all in on rank 0 and broadcast to everyone else.   This approach requires enough memory to stage all the input data at once, or a master-worker scheme where only some data is read in one shot.

Comment: Thansk, I need this just as an example, so we can assume the file is tiny, I do not want to broadcast it but to scatter it, any splitting of the file is fine, I just do not want duplicate lines in different nodes.